# Setup preliminary site list information

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath

I have many lists within a site. As a requirement the site owner should be prompted to add certain information via a form(to Set the prliminary list data). Once this information is filled in the form should dissapear forever.

I was thinking of creating a webpart that sits on the home page and checks if the group of fields requiring preliminary infomation had been filled if they hadn't then show the form.

Is there any other way of doing this than going down the route of creating a custom web part? I have infopath and wondering if it was possible using Infopath

Comment: In the `onet.xml` file, you should define the [`ExecuteUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms435568.aspx) node to point to a custom application page.

Comment: Thanks for the comment i will look in to this